# Ng-repeat is not working at first?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular so I would appreciate any kind of help to resolve this issue.
So I have the following statement

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="item in masterTopicsList" >
```

in my view file.
In my controller file, I have

```
$scope.masterTopicsList = [{name: "test"}];
```

I also have another function:

```
 $scope.addTopic = function () {
   $scope.masterTopicsList.push({name: "anotherTest"});
}
```

The problem is that, my view file is initially empty (shows nothing). But when I click the button that invokes the above function, then the two elements of my `masterTopicsList` show up on the view...

Why is it not working initially for just the first element?

Comment: Are you loading angularjs and your scripts in the <head> or at the bottom of the page?

Comment: It could be the priority of md-list-item. What kind of directive is it? A custom one? A directive from a framework/library? Please add more details on your view, how do you "print" 'item'?

Comment: You have not provided enough information to reproduce the problem. Try creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The example should be … 
 **Complete** – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem

Comment: It should work so the problem is outside of what you have provided. Best take the suggestion of the other commenters and provide more info